# C fscanf to read between square brackets

Tags: c, file, scanf, brackets, square-bracket

I have a file which includes datas as

[name surname] [birthday] [id]

when i try this code

```
while(fscanf(file,"%s %s %s",name,bdate,uid) == 3)
```

bdate gets  surname] as a value

how can i read informations between square brackets.
thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're better off with `fgets()` and a real parser, but try the using [scanf "scanset"](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.2p12) for a quick fix

```
fscanf(file, " [%[^][]] [%[^][]] [%[^][]]", name, bdate, uid)
//            ^        ^        ^           ordinary whitespace
//             ^      ^ ^      ^ ^      ^   ordinary characters
//              ^^---^   ^^---^   ^^---^    scanset specification
//                ^                         "reverse" scanlist
//                 ^^                       characters in scanlist
```

Comment: Are `[]` after `^]` required?

Comment: "Are `[]` after `^]` required?" YES! Note that the `[]` is composed of two distinct funcions: the `[` is part of the scanlist (characters which are to be checked) and the `]` terminates the specification. Also there are a few more '[' and ']' in the `scanf` format string to match literal characters in input.

Comment: I did not understand. Why not `fscanf(file, " [%[^]]] [%[^]]] [%[^]]]", name, bdate, uid)`?